# Map: mix regions and markers

Tags: svg, google-visualization

I need to display both color coded states and cities on a US map.

Is this possible with Google geocharts?
http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options

Basically what I'm looking for is a way to mix the regions and markers display modes.

If not, any alternate options to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644798/google-visualization-can-you-code-u-s-province-level-data-and-some-city-plots), but here it goes again:

Regions and Markers wont work at the same time. So if you want to color the background of the states, using markers mode, you can do it with CSS.

I'm documenting some examples for a Wordpress plugin i developed here: http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/advanced-customization/

Check the last example. It's not easy, since you have to find which child path number you want to color, and then you can do it. Example:

```
#visualization path:nth-child(5) {
fill:#cccccc;
}
```

Here's an example, forkerd from another user, with the CSS above: http://jsfiddle.net/cmoreira/Jqkjg/

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can also color a bunch of states at the same time using some slightly more advanced CSS as follows: `#chart1 path:nth-child(1n + 78) {
fill:#DDDDEE;
    stroke:#888888;
}` This will color all shapes larger than 78. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka2Gq/)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible with GeoCharts. I would recommend you to try [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com) library for that.